# Meniscus shape on complete wetting

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

[image: diagramaticelaboration]What happens when a liquid wets a solid completely , then what will be meniscus shape in long tube , and I recieved answers telling it will be concave.

But in concave , contact angle is non zero and I thought that complete wet must mean contact angle zero , so the meniscus should be cylindrical.

Any explanation ?

Comment: Please clarify the complete wetting or meniscus position, perhaps give a sketch. Typically you obtain a meniscus when a fluid/air interface ends at a another material (a container wall, for example). I can't imagine that happening in complete wetting.

Comment: when a liquid wets a solid, how you are getting meniscus